# Select specific rows from a column in a MATLAB workspace into an array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, matlab, rows

I have a column filled with data in those rows and i would like to select the 1st row from that column but skipping the 2nd row and choosing the 3rd row after and insert them into an array.

Example of the row:

```
'153:154:155:156:157:158:159:160:161:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:170:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:181:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:201:202:203:204:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:223:224:225:226:227:228:229:230:231:232:233:234:235:236:237:238:239:240:241:242:243:244:245:246:247:248:249:250:251:252:253:254:255:256:257:258:259:260:261:262:263:264:265:266:267:268:269:270:271:272:273:274:275:276:277:278:279:280:281:282'
'153:154:155:156:157:158:159:160:161:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:170:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:181:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:201:202:203:204:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:223:224:225:226:227:228:229:230:231:232:233:234:235:236:237:238:239:240:241:242:243:244:245:246:247:248:249:250:251:252:253:254:255:256:257:258:259:260:261:262:263:264:265:266:267:268:269:270:271:272:273:274:275:276:277:278:279:280:281:282'
'30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:131:132:133:134:135:136:137:138:139:140:141:142:143:144:145:146:147:148:149:150:151:152:153:154:155:156:157:158:159:160:161:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:170:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:181:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:201:202:203:204:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:223:224:225:226:227:228:229:230:231:232:233:234:235:236:237:238:239:240:241:242:243:244:245:246:247:248:249:250:251:252:253:254:255:256:257:258:259:260:261:262:263:264:265:266:267:268:269:270:271:272:273:274:275:276:277:278:279:280:281:282:283:284:285:286:287:288:289:290:291:292:293:294:295:296:297:298:299:300:301:302:303:304:305:306:307:308:309:310:311:312:313:314:315:316:317:318:319:320:321:322:323:324:325:326:327:328:329:330:331:332:333:334:335:336:337:338:339:340:341:342:343:344:345:346:347:348:349:350:351:352:353:354:355:356:357:358:359:360:361:362:363:364:365:366:367:368:369:370:371:372:373:374:375:376:377:378:379:380:381:382:383:384:385:386:387:388:389:390:391:392:393:394:395:396:397:398:399:400:401:402:403:404:405:406:407:408:409:410:411:412:413:414:415:416:417:418:419:420:421:422:423:424:425:426:427:428:429:430:431:432:433:434:435:436:437:438:439:440:441:442:443:444:445:446:447:448:449:450:451:452:453:454:455:456:457:458:459:460:461:462:463:464:465:466:467:468:469:470:471:472:473:474:475:476:477:478:479:480:481:482:483:484:485:486:487:488:489:490:491:492:493:494:495:496:497:498:499:500:501:502:503:504:505:506:507:508:509:510:511:512:513:514:515:516:517:518:519:520:521:522:523:524:525:526:527:528:529:530:531:532:533:534:535:536:537:538:539:540:541:542:543:544:545:546:547:548:549:550:551:552:553:554:555:556:557:558:559:560:561:562:563:564:565:566:567:568:569:570:571:572:573:574:575:576:577:578:579:580:581:582:583:584:585:586:587:588:589:590:591:592:593:594:595:596:597:598:599:600:601:602:603:604:605:606:607:608:609:610:611:612:613:614:615:616:617:618:619:620:621:622:623:624:625:626:627:628:629:630:631:632:633:634:635:636:637:638:639:640:641:642:643:644:645:646:647:648:649:650:651:652:653:654:655:656:657:658:659:660:661:662:670:671:672:673:674:675:676:677:678:679:680:681:682:683:684:685:686:687:688:689:690:691:692:693:694:695:696:697:698:699:700:701:702:703:704:705:706:707:708:709:710:711:712:713:714:715:716:717:718:719:720:721:722:723:724:725:726:727:728:729:730:731:732:733:734:735:736:737:738:739:740:741:742:750:751:752:753:754:755:756:757:758:759:760:761:762:763:764:765:766:767:768:769:770:771:772:773:774:775:776:777:778:779:780:781:782:783:784:785:786:787:788:789:790:791:792:793:794:795:796:797:798:799:800:801:802:803:804:805:806:807:808:809:810:811:812:813:814:815:816:817:818:819:820:821:822:823:824:825:826:827:828:829:830:831:832:833:834:835:836:837:838:839:840:841:842:843:844:845:846:847:848:849:850:851:852:853:854:855:856:857:858:859:860:861:862:863:864:865:866:867:868:869:870:871:872:873:874:875:876:877:878:879:880:881:882:883:884:885:886:887:888:889:890:891:892:893:894:895:896:897:898:899:900:901:902:903:904:905:906:907:908:909:910:911:912:913:914:915:916:917:918:919:920:921:922:923:924:925:926:927:928:929:930:931:932:933:934:935:936:937:938:939:940:941:942:943:944:945:946:947:948:949:950:951:952:953:954:955:956:957:958:959:960:961:962:963:964:965:966:967:968:969:970:971:972:973:974:975:976:977:978:979:980:981:982:983:984:985:986:987:988:989:990:991:992:993:994:995:996:997:998:999:1000:1001:1002:1003:1004:1005:1006:1007:1008:1009:1010:1011:1012:1013:1014:1015:1016:1017:1018:1019:1020:1021:1022:1023:1024:1025:1026:1027:1028:1029:1030:1031:1032:1033:1034:1035:1036:1037:1038:1039:1040:1041:1042:1043:1044:1045:1046:1047:1048:1049:1050:1051:1052:1053:1054:1055:1056:1057:1058:1059:1060:1061:1062:1063:1064:1065:1066:1067:1068:1069:1070:1071:1072:1073:1074:1075:1076:1077:1078:1079:1080:1081:1082:1083:1084:1085:1086:1087:1088:1089:1090:1091:1092:1093:1094:1095:1096:1097:1098:1099:1100:1101:1102:1103:1104:1105:1106:1107:1108:1109:1110:1111:1112:1113:1114:1115:1116:1117:1118:1119:1120:1121:1122:1123:1124:1125:1126:1127:1128:1129:1130:1131:1132:1133:1134:1135:1136:1137:1138:1139:1140:1141:1142:1143:1144:1145:1146:1147:1148:1149:1150:1151:1152:1153:1154:1155:1156:1157:1158:1159:1160:1161:1162:1163:1164:1165:1166:1167:1168:1169:1170:1171:1172:1173:1174:1175:1176:1177:1178:1179:1180:1181:1182:1183:1184:1185:1186:1187:1188:1189:1190:1191:1192:1193:1194:1195:1196:1197:1198:1199:1200:1201:1202:1203:1204:1205:1206:1207:1208:1209:1210:1211:1212:1213:1214:1215:1216:1217:1218:1219:1220:1221:1222:1223:1224:1225:1226:1227:1228:1229:1230:1231:1232:1233:1234:1235:1236:1237:1238:1239:1240:1241:1242:1243:1244:1245:1246:1247:1248:1249:1250:1251:1252:1253:1254:1255:1256:1257:1258:1259:1260:1261:1262:1263:1264:1265:1266:1267:1268:1269:1270:1271:1272:1273:1274:1275:1276:1277:1278:1279:1280:1281:1282:1283:1284:1285:1286:1287:1288:1289:1290:1291:1292:1293:1294:1295:1296:1297:1298:1299:1300:1301:1302:1303:1304:1305:1306:1307:1308:1309:1310:1311:1312:1313:1314:1315:1316:1317:1318:1319:1320:1321:1322:1323:1324:1325:1326:1327:1328:1329:1330:1331:1332:1333:1334:1335:1336:1337:1338:1339:1340:1341:1342:1343:1344:1345:1346:1347:1348:1349:1350:1351:1352:1353:1354:1355:1356:1357:1358:1359:1360:1361:1362:1363:1364:1365:1366:1367:1368:1369:1370:1371:1372:1373:1374:1375:1376:1377:1378:1379:1380:1381:1382:1383:1384:1385:1386:1387:1388:1389:1390:1391:1392:1393:1394:1395:1396:1397:1398:1399:1400:1401:1402:1403:1404:1405:1406:1407:1408:1409:1410:1411:1412:1413:1414:1415:1416:1417:1418:1419:1420:1421:1422:1423:1424:1425:1426:1427:1428:1429:1430:1431:1432:1433:1434:1435:1436:1437:1438:1439:1440:1441:1442:1443:1444:1445:1446:1447:1448:1449:1450:1451:1452:1453:1454:1455:1456:1457:1458:1459:1460:1461:1462:1463:1464:1465:1466:1467:1468:1469:1470:1471:1472:1473:1474:1475:1476:1477:1478:1479:1480:1481:1482:1483:1484:1485:1486:1487:1488:1489:1490:1491:1492:1493:1494:1495:1496:1497:1498:1499:1500:1501:1502:1503:1504:1505:1506:1507:1508:1509:1510:1511:1512:1513:1514:1515:1516:1517:1526:1527:1528:1529:1530:1531:1532:1533:1534:1535:1536:1537:1538:1539:1540:1541:1542:1543:1544:1545:1546:1547:1548:1549:1550:1551:1552:1553:1554:1555:1556:1557:1558:1559:1560:1561:1562:1563:1564:1565:1566:1567:1568:1569:1570:1571:1572:1573:1574:1575:1576:1577:1578:1579:1580:1581:1582:1583:1584:1585:1586:1587:1588:1589:1590:1591:1592:1593:1594:1595:1596:1597:1598:1599:1600:1601:1602:1603:1604:1605:1606:1607:1608:1609:1610:1611:1612:1613:1614:1615:1616:1617:1618:1619:1620:1621:1622:1623:1624:1625:1626:1627:1628:1629:1630:1631:1632:1633:1634:1635:1636:1637:1638:1639:1640:1641:1642:1643:1644:1645:1646:1647:1648:1649:1650:1651:1652:1653:1654:1655:1656:1657:1658:1659:1660:1661'
'30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:131:132:133:134:135:136:137:138:139:140:141:142:143:144:145:146:147:148:149:150:151:152:153:154:155:156:157:158:159:160:161:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:170:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:181:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:201:202:203:204:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:223:224:225:226:227:228:229:230:231:232:233:234:235:236:237:238:239:240:241:242:243:244:245:246:247:248:249:250:251:252:253:254:255:256:257:258:259:260:261:262:263:264:265:266:267:268:269:270:271:272:273:274:275:276:277:278:279:280:281:282:283:284:285:286:287:288:289:290:291:292:293:294:295:296:297:298:299:300:301:302:303:304:305:306:307:308:309:310:311:312:313:314:315:316:317:318:319:320:321:322:323:324:325:326:327:328:329:330:331:332:333:334:335:336:337:338:339:340:341:342:343:344:345:346:347:348:349:350:351:352:353:354:355:356:357:358:359:360:361:362:363:364:365:366:367:368:369:370:371:372:373:374:375:376:377:378:379:380:381:382:383:384:385:386:387:388:389:390:391:392:393:394:395:396:397:398:399:400:401:402:403:404:405:406:407:408:409:410:411:412:413:414:415:416:417:418:419:420:421:422:423:424:425:426:427:428:429:430:431:432:433:434:435:436:437:438:439:440:441:442:443:444:445:446:447:448:449:450:451:452:453:454:455:456:457:458:459:460:461:462:463:464:465:466:467:468:469:470:471:472:473:474:475:476:477:478:479:480:481:482:483:484:485:486:487:488:489:490:491:492:493:494:495:496:497:498:499:500:501:502:503:504:505:506:507:508:509:510:511:512:513:514:515:516:517:518:519:520:521:522:523:524:525:526:527:528:529:530:531:532:533:534:535:536:537:538:539:540:541:542:543:544:545:546:547:548:549:550:551:552:553:554:555:556:557:558:559:560:561:562:563:564:565:566:567:568:569:570:571:572:573:574:575:576:577:578:579:580:581:582:583:584:585:586:587:588:589:590:591:592:593:594:595:596:597:598:599:600:601:602:603:604:605:606:607:608:609:610:611:612:613:614:615:616:617:618:619:620:621:622:623:624:625:626:627:628:629:630:631:632:633:634:635:636:637:638:639:640:641:642:643:644:645:646:647:648:649:650:651:652:653:654:655:656:657:658:659:660:661:662:670:671:672:673:674:675:676:677:678:679:680:681:682:683:684:685:686:687:688:689:690:691:692:693:694:695:696:697:698:699:700:701:702:703:704:705:706:707:708:709:710:711:712:713:714:715:716:717:718:719:720:721:722:723:724:725:726:727:728:729:730:731:732:733:734:735:736:737:738:739:740:741:742:750:751:752:753:754:755:756:757:758:759:760:761:762:763:764:765:766:767:768:769:770:771:772:773:774:775:776:777:778:779:780:781:782:783:784:785:786:787:788:789:790:791:792:793:794:795:796:797:798:799:800:801:802:803:804:805:806:807:808:809:810:811:812:813:814:815:816:817:818:819:820:821:822:823:824:825:826:827:828:829:830:831:832:833:834:835:836:837:838:839:840:841:842:843:844:845:846:847:848:849:850:851:852:853:854:855:856:857:858:859:860:861:862:863:864:865:866:867:868:869:870:871:872:873:874:875:876:877:878:879:880:881:882:883:884:885:886:887:888:889:890:891:892:893:894:895:896:897:898:899:900:901:902:903:904:905:906:907:908:909:910:911:912:913:914:915:916:917:918:919:920:921:922:923:924:925:926:927:928:929:930:931:932:933:934:935:936:937:938:939:940:941:942:943:944:945:946:947:948:949:950:951:952:953:954:955:956:957:958:959:960:961:962:963:964:965:966:967:968:969:970:971:972:973:974:975:976:977:978:979:980:981:982:983:984:985:986:987:988:989:990:991:992:993:994:995:996:997:998:999:1000:1001:1002:1003:1004:1005:1006:1007:1008:1009:1010:1011:1012:1013:1014:1015:1016:1017:1018:1019:1020:1021:1022:1023:1024:1025:1026:1027:1028:1029:1030:1031:1032:1033:1034:1035:1036:1037:1038:1039:1040:1041:1042:1043:1044:1045:1046:1047:1048:1049:1050:1051:1052:1053:1054:1055:1056:1057:1058:1059:1060:1061:1062:1063:1064:1065:1066:1067:1068:1069:1070:1071:1072:1073:1074:1075:1076:1077:1078:1079:1080:1081:1082:1083:1084:1085:1086:1087:1088:1089:1090:1091:1092:1093:1094:1095:1096:1097:1098:1099:1100:1101:1102:1103:1104:1105:1106:1107:1108:1109:1110:1111:1112:1113:1114:1115:1116:1117:1118:1119:1120:1121:1122:1123:1124:1125:1126:1127:1128:1129:1130:1131:1132:1133:1134:1135:1136:1137:1138:1139:1140:1141:1142:1143:1144:1145:1146:1147:1148:1149:1150:1151:1152:1153:1154:1155:1156:1157:1158:1159:1160:1161:1162:1163:1164:1165:1166:1167:1168:1169:1170:1171:1172:1173:1174:1175:1176:1177:1178:1179:1180:1181:1182:1183:1184:1185:1186:1187:1188:1189:1190:1191:1192:1193:1194:1195:1196:1197:1198:1199:1200:1201:1202:1203:1204:1205:1206:1207:1208:1209:1210:1211:1212:1213:1214:1215:1216:1217:1218:1219:1220:1221:1222:1223:1224:1225:1226:1227:1228:1229:1230:1231:1232:1233:1234:1235:1236:1237:1238:1239:1240:1241:1242:1243:1244:1245:1246:1247:1248:1249:1250:1251:1252:1253:1254:1255:1256:1257:1258:1259:1260:1261:1262:1263:1264:1265:1266:1267:1268:1269:1270:1271:1272:1273:1274:1275:1276:1277:1278:1279:1280:1281:1282:1283:1284:1285:1286:1287:1288:1289:1290:1291:1292:1293:1294:1295:1296:1297:1298:1299:1300:1301:1302:1303:1304:1305:1306:1307:1308:1309:1310:1311:1312:1313:1314:1315:1316:1317:1318:1319:1320:1321:1322:1323:1324:1325:1326:1327:1328:1329:1330:1331:1332:1333:1334:1335:1336:1337:1338:1339:1340:1341:1342:1343:1344:1345:1346:1347:1348:1349:1350:1351:1352:1353:1354:1355:1356:1357:1358:1359:1360:1361:1362:1363:1364:1365:1366:1367:1368:1369:1370:1371:1372:1373:1374:1375:1376:1377:1378:1379:1380:1381:1382:1383:1384:1385:1386:1387:1388:1389:1390:1391:1392:1393:1394:1395:1396:1397:1398:1399:1400:1401:1402:1403:1404:1405:1406:1407:1408:1409:1410:1411:1412:1413:1414:1415:1416:1417:1418:1419:1420:1421:1422:1423:1424:1425:1426:1427:1428:1429:1430:1431:1432:1433:1434:1435:1436:1437:1438:1439:1440:1441:1442:1443:1444:1445:1446:1447:1448:1449:1450:1451:1452:1453:1454:1455:1456:1457:1458:1459:1460:1461:1462:1463:1464:1465:1466:1467:1468:1469:1470:1471:1472:1473:1474:1475:1476:1477:1478:1479:1480:1481:1482:1483:1484:1485:1486:1487:1488:1489:1490:1491:1492:1493:1494:1495:1496:1497:1498:1499:1500:1501:1502:1503:1504:1505:1506:1507:1508:1509:1510:1511:1512:1513:1514:1515:1516:1517:1526:1527:1528:1529:1530:1531:1532:1533:1534:1535:1536:1537:1538:1539:1540:1541:1542:1543:1544:1545:1546:1547:1548:1549:1550:1551:1552:1553:1554:1555:1556:1557:1558:1559:1560:1561:1562:1563:1564:1565:1566:1567:1568:1569:1570:1571:1572:1573:1574:1575:1576:1577:1578:1579:1580:1581:1582:1583:1584:1585:1586:1587:1588:1589:1590:1591:1592:1593:1594:1595:1596:1597:1598:1599:1600:1601:1602:1603:1604:1605:1606:1607:1608:1609:1610:1611:1612:1613:1614:1615:1616:1617:1618:1619:1620:1621:1622:1623:1624:1625:1626:1627:1628:1629:1630:1631:1632:1633:1634:1635:1636:1637:1638:1639:1640:1641:1642:1643:1644:1645:1646:1647:1648:1649:1650:1651:1652:1653:1654:1655:1656:1657:1658:1659:1660:1661'
'2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:131:132:133:134:135:136'
'1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:131:132:133:134:135:136:137:138:139:140:141'
'1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:52A:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:82A:82B:82C:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:100A:100B:100C:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:133:134:135:136:137:138:139:140:141:142:143:144:145:146:147:148:149:150:151:152:153:154:156:157:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:203:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:225:226:227'
'1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10:11:12:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:52A:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:82A:82B:82C:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:100A:100B:100C:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:133:134:135:136:137:138:139:140:141:142:143:144:145:146:147:148:149:150:151:152:153:154:156:157:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:203:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:225:226:227'
'1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:13:14:15:16:17:18:19:20:21:22:23:24:25:26:27:28:29:30:31:32:33:34:35:36:37:38:39:40:41:42:43:44:45:46:47:48:49:50:51:52:53:54:55:56:57:58:59:60:61:62:63:64:65:66:67:68:69:70:71:72:73:74:75:76:77:78:79:80:81:82:83:84:85:86:87:88:89:90:91:92:93:94:95:96:97:98:99:100:101:102:103:104:105:106:107:108:109:110:111:112:113:114:115:116:117:118:119:120:121:122:123:124:125:126:127:128:129:130:131:132:133:134:135:136:137:138:139:140:141:142:143:144:145:146:147:148:149:150:151:152:153:154:155:156:157:158:159:160:161:162:163:164:165:166:167:168:169:170:171:172:173:174:175:176:177:178:179:180:181:182:183:184:185:186:187:188:189:190:191:192:193:194:195:196:197:198:199:200:201:202:203:204:205:206:207:208:209:210:211:212:213:214:215:216:217:218:219:220:221:222:223:224:225:226:227:228:229:230:231:232:233:234:235:236:237:238:239:240:241:242:243:244:245:246:247:248:249:250:251:252:253:254:255:256:257:258:259:260:261:262:263:264:265:266:267:268:269:270:271:272:273:274:275:276:277:278:279:280:281:282:283:284:285:286:287:288:289:290:291:292:293:294:295:296:297:298:299:300:301:302:303:304:305:306:307:308:309:310:311:312:313:314:315:316:317:318:319:320:321:322:323'
```

Basically, i would want to select the first row, which is `153....282` and then select the 3rd row which is `30...1661` and repeat this process for all other rows accordingly. From there i would like to then insert those data into an array.

The source of these data are from a PostgreSQL database which i have imported into my workspace.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: So when you import it, its format is a cell array (check that iscell returns 1) of strings? There are a few letters in your data (7th row for example, 52A appears). You want to just ignore these?

Comment: It seems you are confused. The result of a query (without an ORDER BY clause), is unordered by default. If you only want the "odd numbered" rows, you should find some criteria to select them by, using the values of some of the table's columns, e.g. `WHERE gender = 'F'`, or `WHERE keycolumn % 2 == 1`.

Comment: this column that i have displayed in my question relates to few other columns in my workspace. For now, i just would like to select the rows that i have stated in my question. It's not that it is odd, i just would like to select 1 and 3 as it relates to different entities in the table that i have imported in my workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work:

```
output = data([1 3],:);
```

This selects the 1st and 3rd rows of `data`, and adds them to a new variable called `output`.  To select every odd row, use the colon notation and the `end` keyword, like this:

```
output = data(1:2:end, :);
```

This starts at the first row selects every 2nd row until the end.

Comment: Yes. This method works. However, i would like to retrieve the rest of the other rows, accordingly using odd rows. For an example, rows 1,3,5,7,9,11,13. Basically every odd row.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to dump it all to a text file and then use [`importdata()`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html) which will allow you to specify the delimiter character, as in `data = importdata(file.txt,':')`. This will give you a MATLAB array `data` full of numbers, which you can then process as you please.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that after you import your data, it is a cell array of strings, called `A` (this is what it appears to be in your question, because of the single quotes on each line).
First, let's get rid of the the letters appearing in the data, since we probably want just the numbers. We do this with a regular expression replacement:

```
A = cellfun(@(x) regexprep(x, '[^\d:]', ''), A,'UniformOutput',0);
```

Next, we use the [strread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strread.html) function to parse each line into an array of integers

```
B = cellfun(@(x) strread(x, '%d:', -1), A, 'UniformOutput',0);
```

Now each element of B is the array form of the corresponding element of A. So you can get the 3rd row, for example with

```
B{3}
```